# Basin hopping bounded optimisation

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I don't understand how to incorporate bounds into scipy's basinhopping routine.

I've got the following script based on scipy's tutorial to test basinhopping with bounds in one dimension.

```
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MyBounds:
    def __init__(self, xmax, xmin ):
        self.xmax = np.array(xmax)
        self.xmin = np.array(xmin)
    def __call__(self, **kwargs):
        x = kwargs["x_new"]
        tmax = bool(np.all(x <= self.xmax))
        tmin = bool(np.all(x >= self.xmin))
        return tmax and tmin

my_bounds = MyBounds([-4], [2])

func = lambda x: np.cos(14.5 * x - 0.3) + (x + 0.2) * x
x0=[1.]

minimizer_kwargs = {"method": "BFGS"}
ret = basinhopping(func, x0, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs,
                   niter=2000, accept_test=my_bounds)
print("global minimum: x = %.4f, f(x) = %.4f" % (ret.x, ret.fun))

bounds = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
vals = [func(x) for x in bounds]

plt.plot(bounds, vals)
```

Without the `accept_test = my_bounds` the output is `global minimum: x = -0.1951, f(x) = -1.0009`. With this line included, it outputs `global minimum: x = 1.0926, f(x) = 0.4259`. This doesn't make sense - -0.1951 is included in [-4, 2] so shouldn't it be the output when the bounds are applied?

Also, changing the bounds to [4, 0] outputs `global minimum: x = 1.0926, f(x) = 0.4259`. This isn't even in the bounds.

What's the right way to handle this in scipy?

Answer (score 0):

Basinhopping invokes Metropolis Hasting to generate step proposals in an iterative fashion. This is stochastic and happens under the hood of the optimizer. However, this is most likely where your answer is hidden. You can uncover the sequence of proposals (and, if they were accepted or not) with the function

```
def debug(x, f, accepted):
    print("f(x)={}, \tIs accepted: {}".format(round(f, 3), int(accepted)))
```

and modifying the line

```
ret = basinhopping(func, x0, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs,
                   niter=2000, accept_test=my_bounds, callback=debug)
```

in your code.

This prints the status at each step of the iterative procedure. You will be able to see where steps are not accepted (keeping the optimizer away from the minimum you expect.)

However, `x = -0.1951` is in the interval `[-4, 2]`. The same is true for `x = 1.0926` and `[0, 4]`. Unfortunately, the `myBounds.__init__(self, xmax, xmin)` has a counterintuitive order of parameters listing the large one first and the small one last.